# данные в datagridview видны только при выделении ячейки

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Номер детали", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Номер программы", typeof(string));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   table.Rows.Add("ytwyetwe", "gswdhsgd");
}
dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
```

Visual studio 2013 пересмотрел много примеров, во всех данные в таблице видны сразу у меня только при выделении, т.е. при запуске приложения вся таблица пустая (белая) при нажатии на любую ячейку она (ячейка) становится синей и в ней видны данные.Код расположен в Form_load Спасибо!

Comment: цвет шрифта наверное белый задан где-то

Comment: Перейдите в дизайн режим. Выделите грид посмотрите свойства и измените цвет шрифта